# Limiting resource availability to specific days only in MS Project 2007

Tags: microsoft-project

I am scheduling a project in MS Project 2007 where one of the resources (a developer) only has 2 days available each week. Is there any way I can format the 'rules' for that resource so that the tasks they are responsible for are only scheduled in on the 2 days/week they are available (eg Tuesdays and Thursdays)?

There are a lot of dependencies ("Predecessors") on this one person so it impacts considerable upon the whole project plan.

My only solution at the moment would be to manually move each task for the resource to the relevant days they are available on which is something I would prefer not to do as there are many tasks.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

after a long time later, now I saw your question and wanted to drop a note. you can do this by changing his working times to the days just you wanted. to make this, (on project 2010) go project tab on ribbon and press change working time, select the people you want, go to work weeks tab and press details, select the days which you don't want. now you just have a 2 day working resource.
hope this helps.